# Value does not fall within the expected range. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Everything was working fine until I changed something very small in a report (.rdlc), and now I can't compile my program.

Platform version info:

```
Windows ................ 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime . 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll ... 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
clr.dll     ............. 4.7.3362.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll ............... 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
dfshim.dll ,............ 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
```

Sources:

```
Deployment url          : file:///C:/KORTICK_Shipping/Shipping.application
Application url         : file:///C:/KORTICK_Shipping/Application%20Files/Shipping_1_0_0_143/Shipping.exe.manifest
```

Identities:

```
Deployment Identity     : Shipping.application, Version=1.0.0.143, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af2e04a4ff662ec9, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity    : Shipping.exe, Version=1.0.0.143, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af2e04a4ff662ec9, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
```

Application summary:

```
* Installable application.
```

Error summary:

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\KORTICK_Shipping\Shipping.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Component store transaction failure summary:

```
No transaction error was detected.
```

Warnings:

```
There were no warnings during this operation.
```

Operation progress status:

```
* [03/25/2019 1:18:21 PM] : Activation of C:\KORTICK_Shipping\Shipping.application has started.
* [03/25/2019 1:18:21 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [03/25/2019 1 details::18:21 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
* [03/25/2019 1:18:21 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [03/25/2019 1:18:22 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
* [03/25/2019 1:18:22 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
```

Error details:

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [03/25/2019 1:18:22 PM] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Component store transaction details:

```
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, "Value does not fall within the expected range" usually indicates a value exceeded what .NET was expecting. Typically something like an integer value being too large, string value too long, etc. It would be helpful if you could provide some information about what you changed? Primarily if you've set any values to extremely high, low, or long values?

Comment: `System.ArgumentException - Value does not fall within the expected range` is not a compilation error, it is an exception occurring at runtime.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you haven't included any of the problem code. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks